# Add request header within DefaultRedirectHandler.getLocationURI callback

Tags: android, httpclient

I have the following scenario:

Android HttpClient is redirected to alternative location, the redirection url comes back with a certain url parameter which has to be propagated as extra http header in the redirection request. The only way to interfere is to override the DefaultRedirectHandler.getLocationURI handler. 
Now my question: how within

```
public URI getLocationURI(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
```

I can modify the out-coming request.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an implementation of `RedirectHandler` and overwrite `getLocationURI()`. You can get the redirect url by

```
    Header locationHeader = response.getFirstHeader("location");
    String location = locationHeader.getValue();
```

extract your url parameter from `location` and then you could get the `HttpRequest` by

```
    BasicHttpRequest request = (BasicHttpRequest) context.getAttribute(
                            ExecutionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    header.addHeader();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, most likely I had to mention all ways I already tried but nothing, except of interrupting the request redirection and creating absolutely new request manually, only worked. Your suggestion was my first trial and it has to be HttpUriRequest request = (HttpUriRequest) context.getAttribute( ExecutionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);  and it didn't work actually, the ExecutionContext.HTTP_REQUEST refers to the original request and not to the out coming. As I said to make redirect manually, I know. I look for more elegant way to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found as feasible to modify a redirection request is to interrupt the original one and create new request manually within

```
  RedirectHandler and overwrite getLocationURI()
```

The original request is interrupted and throws

```
 IllegalStateException
```